# Desconocido motor de tabla 'InnoDB'

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, innodb

**Problema**

Estoy tratando de acceder a la información almacenada en mi Base de Datos pero al momento de hacer clic en la tabla arroja el siguiente error:

[image: Error INNODB]

También cabe aclarar que esto hasta el día de ayer funcionaba correctamente y no presentaba ningún problema. Hasta el punto en que el tamaño de las tablas aparece en **0 bytes**.

**Servidor**

- Tipo: Compartido
- Interfaz: Cpanel

También verifiqué el motor de mysql dentro de la interfaz de phpmyadmin y esto fue lo que pude notar (InnoDB al parecer está inhabilitado para el servidor compartido) esto en comparación desde el localhost de Xampp:

**Compartido**
[image: Shared Server]

**Xampp Localhost**
[image: Localhost]

¿Alguien se ha encontrado con este problema y ha podido solucionarlo de alguna manera, me preocupa el hecho de que se haya eliminado la información que tenía en esa base de datos?

Comment: Creo que se daÑo

Comment: Parece ser que se desabilito el soporte para innodb, debes buscar en Xamp el directorio de mysql y buscar en my.cnf o my.ini  -> `skip-innodb` y comentarlo.

Comment: El problema es que no es en Xampp sino más bien en el servidor compartido; había pensado que era solo en mi sitio pero al notar el sitio de mi proveedor también se vio afectado por este suceso. Pero pregunto si habrá alguna manera de solucionar en el Servidor compartido.

Comment: Al ser un servidor compartido el único que lo puede arreglar es el mismo proveedor, te sugiero los contactes y notifiques

Comment: En todo caso, si desactivas el soporte para InnoDB y reinicias mysql lo único que ocurre físicamente es que MySQL ignora la representación física de las tablas. No se borran si no hay un acto deliberado.